# Linux command to start spring boot application

Tags: java, linux, unix

I have a spring boot application which runs on jdk 11 and i need to deploy the application in linux server.

In linux server i have jdk 8 installed and due to java version mismatch, i am not able to start the application in linux server. There are other applications which are running on the same linux server with jdk 8, so i don't want to disturb them and i have installed jdk 11 on a separate folder in linux server and now i want to run my application using jdk 11.

I am using the below command to start the application

```
java -cp test-api-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar com.test.api.TestAPIApplication
```

But it is taking jdk 8 by default and not starting up
How to modify the command to take the jdk 11 path

Answer (score 0):

update jdk reference in pom.xml to point to jdk 11

Comment: I have tried that but still getting below exception 
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to open nested entry 'BOOT-IN                                                                             F/lib/spring-boot-starter-data-rest-2.3.8.RELEASE.jar'. It has been compressed a                                                                             nd nested jar files must be stored without compression. Please check the mechani                                                                             sm used to create your executable jar file